# Router not assigning DHCP IP Addresses to Interconnecting Switches

Tags: router, switch, vlan, dhcp, fiber

I am having problems connecting from some of my switches to the router/internet. I have a Cisco 1900 series router with four different 2960 series switches. All Gigabit Ethernet ports are configured to be trunk. The router is connected to FF_Switch using the Gig0/1 port while the Gig0/2 port is connected to a Fiber/T Transceiver(Fiber connection converted to RJ45 using Fiber/T Transceiver) passed over fiber connection to another Fiber/T Transceiver, from which it is connected to Gig0/1 of SVOSwitch2. Gig0/2 of SVOSwitch2 connects to Gig0/1 of SVOSwitch3. Gig0/2 of SVOSwitch3 connects to Gig0/1 of SVOSwitch1.

SVOSwitch1 has the ports on VLAN1 and 3, SVOSwitch2 has the ports on VLAN 4 and 5 while SVO Switch 3 has the ports on VLAN 5 and 6.

The problem is that whenever I connect to any of the ports, I can only connect and get DHCP on the ports on VLAN 1 and 4.

The configuration for the router is given below;

```
    ip dhcp pool FF_SWITCH
network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
default-router 192.168.1.1 
!
ip dhcp pool SVOSwitch1
network 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
default-router 192.168.3.1 
!
ip dhcp pool SVOSwitch2
network 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
default-router 192.168.4.1 
!
ip dhcp pool SVOSwitchVlanPool1
network 192.168.6.0 255.255.255.0
dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
default-router 192.168.6.1 
!
ip dhcp pool SVOSwitch3
network 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0
dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
default-router 192.168.5.1 
!
ip dhcp pool SVOSwitchVlanPool2
network 192.168.7.0 255.255.255.0
dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
default-router 192.168.7.1

interface GigabitEthernet0/0
description ### WAN INTERFACE ###
ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 255.255.xxx.xxx
ip flow ingress
ip nat outside
ip virtual-reassembly in
duplex full
speed auto
no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
description ### LAN INTERFACE ###
no ip address
ip flow ingress
ip virtual-reassembly in
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1
description ###1st FLR NETWORK ###
encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip access-group 110 in
ip accounting output-packets
ip flow ingress
ip flow egress
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.3
description ### TNB WIRELESS NETWORK ###
encapsulation dot1Q 3
ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
ip access-group 110 in
ip accounting output-packets
ip flow ingress
ip flow egress
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.4
description ### TNB 1ST WING NETWORK ###
encapsulation dot1Q 4
ip address 192.168.4.1 255.255.255.0
ip access-group 110 in
ip accounting output-packets
ip flow ingress
ip flow egress
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.5
description ### TNB 2ND WING NETWORK ###
encapsulation dot1Q 5
ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
ip access-group 110 in
ip accounting output-packets
ip flow ingress
ip flow egress
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.6
description ### TNB PENTHOUSE NETWORK ###
encapsulation dot1Q 6
ip address 192.168.6.1 255.255.255.0
ip access-group 110 in
ip accounting output-packets
ip flow ingress
ip flow egress
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.7
description ### TNB OTHER NETWORK ###
encapsulation dot1Q 7
ip address 192.168.7.1 255.255.255.0
ip access-group 110 in
ip accounting output-packets
ip flow ingress
ip flow egress
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
switchport access vlan 100
no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3
no ip address
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
!
interface Vlan100
ip address xxx.xxx.xxd.ddd xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip http timeout-policy idle 60 life 86400 requests 10000
ip flow-export source GigabitEthernet0/1
ip flow-export version 9
ip flow-export destination 192.168.1.120 9996
!
ip nat inside source list NAT interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
!
ip access-list standard NAT
permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
permit 192.168.3.0 0.0.0.255
permit 192.168.4.0 0.0.0.255
permit 192.168.5.0 0.0.0.255
permit 192.168.6.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
snmp-server community public RO
snmp-server community private RW
snmp-server ifindex persist
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

As Avery Abbott requested, here is it from SVOSwitch3

```
SVOSwitch3#show vlan brief

VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    
5    VLAN0005                         active    Fa0/1, Fa0/2, Fa0/3, Fa0/4
                                                Fa0/5, Fa0/6
6    VLAN0006                         active    Fa0/7, Fa0/8, Fa0/9, Fa0/10
                                                Fa0/11, Fa0/12, Fa0/13, Fa0/14
                                                Fa0/15, Fa0/16, Fa0/17, Fa0/18
                                                Fa0/19, Fa0/20, Fa0/21, Fa0/22
                                                Fa0/23, Fa0/24
1002 fddi-default                     act/unsup 
1003 token-ring-default               act/unsup 
1004 fddinet-default                  act/unsup 
1005 trnet-default                    act/unsup 


SVOSwitch3#show interface trun    

Port        Mode             Encapsulation  Status        Native vlan
Gi0/1       on               802.1q         trunking      1
Gi0/2       on               802.1q         trunking      1

Port        Vlans allowed on trunk
Gi0/1       1-4094
Gi0/2       1-4094

Port        Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi0/1       1,5-6
Gi0/2       1,5-6

Port        Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi0/1       1,5-6
Gi0/2       1,5-6
SVOSwitch3#show run int gi0/1
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 59 bytes
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport mode trunk
end

SVOSwitch3#show run int gi0/2
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 59 bytes
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport mode trunk
end
```

And for the running config, I have,

```
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname SVOSwitch3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 1/
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
system mtu routing 1500
!
!
!
!         
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-14
     enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-14
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-14
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-14
  quit
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 5
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 5
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 5
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 5
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 5
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 6
!         
interface FastEthernet0/11
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport access vlan 6
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.1.9 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.5.1
ip http server
ip http secure-server
```

That was picked from the SVOSwitch3.

Comment: You stated that you're using Gi0/1 for FF_Switch and Gi0/2 for SVOSwitch2, but your router config says Gi0/0 and Gi0/1.

Does SVOSwitch2 have all the VLANs created and trunked on Gi0/1 and Gi0/2?  Can you provide a "show vlan brief", "show interface trunking", "show run int gi0/1", and "show run int gi0/2" all from SVOSwitch2?

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong: snmp RW is "private" with no ACL on it.  You should change the RO and RW communities ASAP as well as applying an snmp ACL on them

Comment: Avery Abbott, the requested output has been provided. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All thanks to the comment by Avery Abbott, I was able to solve the problem by making sure that all [cascading] switches have the corresponding vlans created so that the trunks can carry data for that vlan across the switch.

thanks all.